# Select specific form in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I don't know if I can do it but what I'm trying is next:

I have a model 'service' which have some fields like: name, help.. and one associatedForm. My idea is use this to generate services interfaces selecting the correct form.

this means to have a view like this:

```
def serviceInterface(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    service = Service.objects.get(serviceName=request.POST.get('Name'))
    form = service.associatedForm
    return render(request, 'serviceInterface.html', {'name': service.name,'form': form})
```

of course, it's not working and in the form template I just see the form name (serviceForm()) but what I want is select the information that I have in my forms.py with that name:

```
 class serviceForm(forms.Form):
  filename = forms.CharField(label='Filename', max_length=100)
  parameter = forms.CharField(label='parameter', max_length=1)
  parameter2 = forms.CharField(label='parameter2', max_length=1)
```

of course I know I can do it with a Switch for example and checking the name of the form and so, but the idea is do something more automatic like to create a new service just define the form in forms.py and add the information to your database

Is this possible?

This is my model Service:

```
 class Service (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
   associatedForm = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for form builders? https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/form-builder/ these packages allow you to create forms threw the web.

Comment: I have no problem creating the forms, the problem is how to select one or another without a huge switch with all the options.

Comment: service.associatedForm is a method, not an attribute.  So you need to add () to get your form instance.

Comment: associatedForm is a field of my model Service where I store a name of a form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the result from the db is coming back as a string, you need to get the object. What you are looking for is `getattr`:

```
def serviceInterface(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        service = Service.objects.get(name=request.POST.get('Name'))
        selected_form = getattr(forms, service.associatedForm)
        form = selected_form()
        return render(request, 'serviceInterface.html', {'name': service.name,'form': form})
```

I would recommend wrapping the `getattr` with a `try/except` in case it can't find the named form. and also having a default return/redirect in case the form was not found.

Hope this helps

see [docs](http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm)

Comment: Hi Incognos! This looks exactly that I'm searching but It throwing me this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'serviceForm' the service name in my case es 'serviceForm', right?

Comment: did you import forms? at the top you have to `import forms` (which has to be importing the right forms file, the one you created, not the django one - you can see what is available in that file by doing a `dir(forms)` ) then below you can call `getattr(forms, service.associatedForm)`

Answer (score 1):

Create all forms, and create a dictionary with the forms
forms.py

```
from django import forms
class FormA(forms.Form):
    filename = forms.CharField(label='Filename', max_length=100)
    parameter = forms.CharField(label='parameter', max_length=1)
    parameter2 = forms.CharField(label='parameter2', max_length=1)
class FormB(forms.Form):
    filename = forms.CharField(label='Filename', max_length=100)
    parameter = forms.CharField(label='parameter', max_length=1)
    parameter2 = forms.CharField(label='parameter2', max_length=1)
class FormC(forms.Form):
    filename = forms.CharField(label='Filename', max_length=100)
    parameter = forms.CharField(label='parameter', max_length=1)
    parameter2 = forms.CharField(label='parameter2', max_length=1)
class FormD(forms.Form):
    filename = forms.CharField(label='Filename', max_length=100)
    parameter = forms.CharField(label='parameter', max_length=1)
    parameter2 = forms.CharField(label='parameter2', max_length=1)
```

views.py

the associatedForm you can get from POST, o database

```
def serviceInterface(request):
    associatedForm = "a" # get form name from data base
    forms = {
        "a":FormA(),
        "b":FormB(),
        "c":FormC(),
        "d":FormD(),
    }
    form = forms[associatedForm]
    # if request.method == POST:
    return render(request,"add.html",{'form':form})
```